# Intersection observer "unloads" images after looping on carousel (Siema)

Tags: javascript, carousel, lazy-loading, intersection-observer, siema

I have this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n3967fr1/6/) to show my problem.

I have made an intersection observer for lazy loading images, code:

```
const images = document.querySelectorAll("[data-src]");

function preloadImage(img){
    const src = img.getAttribute("data-src");
    if (!src) { return; }
    img.src= src;
}

const imgOptions = {
    threshold: 0,
    rootMargin: "0px 0px 300px 0px"
};

const imgObserver = new IntersectionObserver( (entries, imgObserver) => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        if(!entry.isIntersecting){
            return;
        } else {
            preloadImage(entry.target);
            imgObserver.unobserve(entry.target);
        }
    })
}, imgOptions);

images.forEach( image => {
    imgObserver.observe(image);
});
```

The problem arises when I loop through the Siema carousel, the last and first images "unloads", meaning, `src` is returned to `data-src`, despite it being told to  `unobserve` after intersecting.

To see the problem simply click 'prev' in the fiddle. The first image will disappear, but it was already loaded.

Why is this happening, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
[Fixed working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w4ja2xfh/), thank you @ohladkov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because of this value: `loop: 1`. When loading the page in `const images = document.querySelectorAll ("[data-src]")` are only 6 pictures contained, and when you initialize the slider, it has 10 images. You need to get images and call your observer when the slider is initialized. Siema has an onInit callback.
Something like that:

```
onInit() {
  const el = document.querySelector(this.config.selector); // get siema container
  const images = el.querySelectorAll("[data-src]"); // get all siema images

  images.forEach( image => {
    imgObserver.observe(image);
  });
},
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: I didn't even realise carousel added extra images. This fixed it, thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome. Most of carousels add additional items if the loop mode is on and the slides are changed by translate property.